# CSS issue when using different unit types in the same rule

Tags: css, less

I have this CSS rule for a div, a modal with height based on the vertical size of the browser window:

```
height: calc(100vh - 185px);
```

When I use it inline (`<div style="height: calc(100vh - 185px)">`) it works fine, but when I place it in an external css it stops working:

style.css:

```
.order-modal-body {
  height: calc(100vh - 185px);
}
```

page.html

```
<div class="order-modal-body">xyz<div>
```

And it works only if I use same type of units (both vh or px).

Should I use it inline or there is a solution to use the rule in an external css?

EDIT: Using *less* for external styles.

EDIT: An MCVE with the issue and the solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPyPNR

Comment: That's odd. Please make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Would the external CSS be something preprocessed? I hear that some CSS preprocessors have troubles keeping `calc` expressions working.

Comment: It looks like you linked `style.css` to your page incorrectly

Comment: @MrLister yes, I use less

Comment: @neptune In that case, https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/436

Comment: @MrLister Problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use LESS try this:

```
height: calc(~"100vh - 185px");
```